# How to handle header name conflict with standerd library header, but do not change file name?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile tudu project: https://github.com/meskio/tudu and I encountered specific problem: they have `sched.h` file, the same name as used in standard library: `libc6-dev:amd64: /usr/include/sched.h`. The problem is that some other **standard library header** tries to include `sched.h` and it takes the local one instead of library file. This causes errors. Is it possible to setup compiler (include paths or sth) to repair this situation without modifying any file name?

Here is offending include operation:

```
In file included from ./data.h:28,
     from ./sched.h:24,           // <- pthread.h includes local file
                                  // instead of /usr/include/sched.h
     from /usr/include/pthread.h:23,
```

UPDATE:
I dag a bit and found including rules in gcc documentation:

> By default, the preprocessor looks for header files included by the quote form of the directive #include "file" first relative to the directory of the current file, and then in a preconfigured list of standard system directories. For example, if /usr/include/sys/stat.h contains #include "types.h", GCC looks for types.h first in /usr/include/sys, then in its usual search path.
>
> For the angle-bracket form #include , the preprocessor’s default behavior is to look only in the standard system directories. The exact search directory list depends on the target system, how GCC is configured, and where it is installed. You can find the default search directory list for your version of CPP by invoking it with the -v option. For example,

It seems that the second rule is not true in my system and I wonder why. Generally it actually looks for headers in system directories - otherwise the `pthread.h` wouldn't be included. But when `shed.h` is included it shows up that cpp prefers current local directory over system include path and over "same path as file that includes". strange...

Comment: The correct way to exclude local headers is to `#include <...>` rather than `#include "..."`

Comment: But the case is that library header includes wrong file

Comment: libraries should put their headers into a sub directory to avoid this problem, i.e. `#include "tudu/sched.h"`

Comment: Compiles fine for me. What OS and what compiler are you using? What commands did you run?

Comment: ./configure and make. debian buster; I was able to build today on ubuntu but at the moment I don't know the state/configuration of standard library headers there.

Comment: compiler g++ 8.3.0, also tried with a couple of older versions;

Answer (score 0):

I see that the problem was connected with the fact that i had `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` set. The problem with this project is solved but I still don't understand this strange behavior. My `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` was pointing to other, unrelated directories so it shouldn't affect this project (it didn't introduce any additional name conflicts). When CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH is empty or does not exist everything builds correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I know its weird, but I got the same issue while using gcc version 9.3.0 on ubuntu1~20.04. I made a new header sched.h while conflicted with linux usr/include/sched naturally.

I tried using both include "" which should be the natural choice since I had the file in my current directory and then <> just to try my luck (but it was bound to fail).

For anyone that faces this problem just use "../foldername/headerfile.h" to make sure you can point to correct folder.

Hope it helps. Let me know if it can be done better.